# Recursive algorithm for calculating powers

Tags: algorithms, exponentiation

I am working on a maths exercise and got this question:

Make a recursive algorithm on the calculation of $x^p$, where $x$ is a real number and $p$ is a natural number of $n$ bits.

I really don't know where to start. Whats the way of solving this?

Ps. english isn't my first language.

Comment: What is it that you're learning about -- i.e., what is the context of the exercise?

Comment: Note that if it were $x^p$ instead of $p^x$, you would be looking for some variant of [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: The context of the exercise is ICT related. I translated the question from dutch.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Im sorry, I misspelled the question, it is indeed x^p instead of p^x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution for the original formulation** $p^x=?$

Note that $$p^x = \exp(x \log p) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{\log^ip}{i !}x^i.$$

You can now truncate the series at some $i$ and recursively compute the partial sum up to that point.

If you cannot use the logarithm or exponential functions, you could also express $x$ in binary and adapt the [exponentiation by squaring algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

**Solution for the correct formulation** For the corrected version of the problem, where you are asked to compute $x^p$, you can use exponentiation by squaring directly using

$$\begin{align}
x^0&=1\\
x^n&=(x^{n/2})^2 \ \text{for even }n\\
x^n&=x \cdot (x^{(n-1)/2})^2 \ \text{for odd }n
\end{align}
$$

Comment: But that is unlikely to be the intended answer, because it doesn't use the explicitly given fact that $p$ is an integer.